# How to correctly extract special characters from a webpage using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all the text from a webpage given its url using beautifulsoup.
I tried running a code I found here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/how_to_scrape_text_from_webpage_using_beautifulsoup_python

Everything works fine except special characters such as "é" or "à".
I tried a bunch of modifications but I couldn't get it working.
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import codecs

html = requests.get(yourWebsiteURL).content

unicode_str = html.decode('utf8')
encoded_str = unicode_str.encode("ascii",'ignore')
news_soup = BeautifulSoup(encoded_str, "html.parser")
a_text = news_soup.find_all('p')

y=[re.sub(r'<.+?>',r'',str(a)) for a in a_text]

file = codecs.open("textOutput.txt", "wb", encoding='utf-8')
file.write(str(y))
file.close()
```

However, I am sure that the problem is coming from my usage of bs4 since I've never faced this problem when writing to a file.

Comment: As a side note, use `[a.text for a in a_text]` to get the text between `p` tags. You don't need regex for that.

Comment: That's pretty dumb advice given on that page. The question asker doesn't appear to have an understanding of what Unicode text is and the answer you used is a pretty blunt way of dealing with non-ASCII text.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: better still: `[a.get_text() for a in a_text]`, and you can then specify options on how sections are joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
encoded_str = unicode_str.encode("ascii",'ignore')
```

This line of your code encodes your text as ascii. Ascii does not contain special characters such as é or à. I am not sure why you decode from UTF8, which includes those characters, to ascii, which doesn't contain them.

Comment: They can drop decoding too, leave that to BeautifulSoup, there could be metadata in the HTML page that specifies the correct codec.

Comment: yes I changed ascii to utf8 and now it's working perfectly. Thanks !